To get the corresponding character against the Ascii value which is already stored in comma delimited .txt file
Following is my code, to read comma delimited integer(Ascii) value from a .txt file, and storing into integer array. And from integer array to integer, for integer to character conversion. So that I can get the corresponding character against the Ascii value which is already stored in comma delimited .txt file. But in my code there is compilation error. Please help me to fulfil my requirements.
import java.io. File; 
import java.io. FileNotFoundException;  
import java.lang.reflect.Array; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.*;

public class Read_int_array_a  
{ 
    private final static String FILE_NAME = "D:/sumit/sample-project/final/file3.txt"; 
    private final static String DELIMITER = ", "; 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        File inputFile = new File(FILE_NAME); 
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        try  
        { 
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile); 
            scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER); 
            while(scanner.hasNext()) 
            { 
                String value = scanner.next(); 
                Integer num = Integer.parseInt(value); 
                System.out.print(num);
                numbers.add(num);
            } 
            scanner.close();
                System.out.println(" ");
                int[] jcdIntArray = new int[numbers.size()];
                int myInt = 0;
                for(Integer jcdInt : numbers) {
                    jcdIntArray[myInt++] = jcdInt;
                                              }
                for(Integer myInteger : jcdIntArray) {
                    char ch = (char)myInteger;
                    System.out.print(ch);
                                                     }
        } 
           catch (FileNotFoundException e)  
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
         
    } 
}

Data of file3.txt file is bellow :
70, 73, 78, 65, 78, 67, 73, 65, 76, 32, 80, 82, 79, 68, 85, 67, 84, 83, 32, 68, 73, 83, 84, 82, 73, 66, 85, 84, 73, 79, 78, 32, 76, 73, 77, 73, 84, 69, 68

Unclear why you need the array. Just loop over the list

You can make this at lot easier with List<Integer> ints = null;try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(FILE_NAME))).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*")) {ints = s.tokens().map(c ->c.codePointAt(0)).toList();}

Incidentally, you can turn that collection ints back into a String simply by doing: String s = ints.stream().map(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

@user7616778 - Someone provided an answer, why didn't you confirm the answer and then posted a very similar question?  To get the corresponding character against the Ascii value which is already stored in comma delimited .txt file, will print at .pdf file ( "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78689934/to-get-the-corresponding-character-against-the-ascii-value-which-is-already-stor")

The problem in your code is this line:
char ch = (char)myInteger;

An Integer is not the same as an int.
Integer is an object whereas int is a primitive.
Therefore the cast does not work since an object cannot be cast to a primitive.
Hence all you need to do in order for your code to compile and produce correct results is to use int rather than Integer, i.e. change this line of your code:
for (Integer myInteger : jcdIntArray) {

to this:
for (int myInteger : jcdIntArray) {

In other words, replace Integer with int.
For the sake of completeness, here is your code with the above correction.
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Read_int_array_a {
    private final static String FILE_NAME = "D:/sumit/sample-project/final/file3.txt";
    private final static String DELIMITER = ", ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
            scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String value = scanner.next();
                Integer num = Integer.parseInt(value);
                System.out.print(num);
                numbers.add(num);
            }
            scanner.close();
            System.out.println(" ");
            int[] jcdIntArray = new int[numbers.size()];
            int myInt = 0;
            for (Integer jcdInt : numbers) {
                jcdIntArray[myInt++] = jcdInt;
            }
            for (int myInteger : jcdIntArray) {
                char ch = (char) myInteger;
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

When I run the above code, with the sample data you posted in your question, I get the following output:
FINANCIAL PRODUCTS DISTRIBUTION LIMITED

Now let me propose an alternate solution that uses NIO.2 and streams and lambda expressions and method references and try-with-resources.
/*
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
*/
Path path = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    lines.flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(DELIMITER)))
         .map(Integer::parseInt)
         .map(Character::toString)
         .forEach(System.out::print);
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}


Thanks I Got My solutions.  Code is performing perfectly.

like "+1" "Thanks"

Your compilation fails because you can't just convert Integer to char.
According to this question you should replace
char ch = (char)myInteger;

with something like
char ch = Character.forDigit(myInteger, 10);


I think you misunderstood the question. The numbers represent ASCII codes and the OP wants to convert each code to its corresponding character, e.g. 65 should be converted to uppercase letter A.

With a few changes, your code works:
after the line:
String value = scanner.next();

add
value = value.replaceAll( " ", "" );

to remove the last empty space, which is after the "68".
then we change the line
char ch = (char)myInteger;

by
char ch = ( char ) ( ( ( int ) myInteger );  

since char does not work with Integer, and... work!.

Avoid char
The char type in Java has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters.
Instead make a habit of using Unicode code point integer numbers, as seen below.
Basically a one-liner
Use the Paths & Files utility classes in Java NIO.2 to easily read the contents of your input file. No need for Scanner.
Split the line of text by its delimiter of COMMA & SPACE characters. You get an array of String objects, one per field in your row of data from the input text file.
Make that array of strings into a stream for easy code to further process.
Make an integer number of each of those streamed string objects. Each number represents a Unicode code point number according to you.
For defensive programming, check that each streamed integer number actually is a valid Unicode code point.
Transform each code point into text, into the character mapped to that code point as officially documented in the Unicode standard.
Collect all those individual characters into one final piece of text, our resulting String object.
Here is a complete example app to fulfill your purpose.
Path filePath = Paths.get( "/Users/basil_dot_work/codePoints.txt" );
String result = null;
try
{
    result =
            Arrays                                            // Utility class.
                    .stream(                                  // Create a stream from an array. In our case here, an array of `String` objects.
                            Files                             // Utility class. Part of Java NIO.2.
                                    .readString( filePath )   // Reads all content from a file into a string, reading octets as characters per UTF-8 character encoding.
                                    .split( ", " )            // Splits the string by specified delimiter. Result is an array of `String` objects. In our case here, each string contains the text of digits for each number in file.
                    )                                         // Returns a Stream of `String` objects.
                    .map( Integer :: valueOf )                // Returns a `Stream` of `Integer` objects. Transforms our text into numbers, each representing a Unicode code point.
                    .filter( Character :: isValidCodePoint )  // Removes any number which is not a valid Unicode code point.
                    .map( Character :: toString )             // Returns a `Stream` of `String` object, each string being a single-character, the character represented by the code point.
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.joining( )             // Returns a `Collector` that concatenates the input elements into a `String`.
                    );                                        // Returns a `String` object, containing the text intended by the publisher of our input text file.
} catch ( IOException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace( );
}
System.out.println( "result = " + result );

When run:
result = FINANCIAL PRODUCTS DISTRIBUTION LIMITED

